# Undefined argument list

Tags: c++

I have a C++ template class (in Qt) that should handle a list of custom items. This class has a simple member function that is supposed to call the constructor of the template type and add the created item to the list.

```
void CustomList::addElement(void)
{
    T *element = new T();
    // ...
}
```

But I have a problem : I'd like this function to be able to call overloaded constructors.

I thought I could give it the arguments that should be used in the constructor. So it would be called with as arguments a "copy" of the arguments given to addElement().

Except that I don't know how many of them there are, no more than their types. Any simple way I could do it ?

Comment: Variadic templates, if you can use C++11

Comment: Lots and lots of overloads, if you can't use C++11. So use C++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So it would be called with as arguments a "copy" of the arguments
>   given to addElement().

Why copies when you can use the original arguments?

With C++11 you can use variadic templates and perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename... Args>
void CustomList::addElement(Args&&... args)
{
    T *element = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // ...
}
```

Without proper C++11 support you will have to overload the `addElement` function (template) for every amount of arguments until a sensible limit is reached. I.e.

```
template <typename Arg1>
void CustomList::addElement(Arg1 const& arg1)
{
    T *element = new T(arg1);
    // ...
}

template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
void CustomList::addElement(Arg1 const& arg1, Arg2 const& arg2)
{
    T *element = new T(arg1, arg2);
    // ...
}

// [...]
```

Comment: +1 for bringing code examples. Works fine, thank you !

Comment: Recently, I had to use variadic templates with no standard library. I used `args...` instead of `std::forward<Args>(args)...`. I wonder, what's the difference ?

Comment: @Lephe This answer was already answered on SO. Look for "perfect forwaring"